# "Save as" dialog box not activated on Amazon ec2 instance (windows 2008), when rdp session is closed

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008, autoit, selenium-webdriver, rdp

I am running Selenium and Autoit on Amazon ec2 instance to test my website on firefox. The testcases are triggered automatically every hour using task scheduler. I am using Autoit to handle "save as" dialog box for some file download type testcases.

This process works when i am connected to ec2 instance using rdp. But when i close the session to rdp, my autoit script fails to handle "save as" dialog box. It stuck on  WinWaitActive function. The reason, that seems to me is, when rdp connection is closed to amazon, it does not activate save as dialog box.
If i telnet on rdp port, my testcase works fine.

Is there is any way to fix this? Is there any setting in rdp server where i can say connection is always on? Or can i use some alternative command on autoit that deliberately chose save button on save as dialog box and save the file in a folder.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i am able to run file download testcases. The solution is to add VNC server.

I installed tightvnc and ran it as a service. Configured the firewall and security access for selenium, connected from vnc client. And then it worked after closing VNC and RDP connection to the server.